# Article 3 of the Protocol to the Convention for the Protection of Human Rights and Fundamental Freedoms of ECHR, has it ever been used?

Tags: european-union, elections, case-law, european-court-of-human-rights, hungary

This question arises out of a previous question on Hungary's prospects to  overturn autocratic rule after an unlikely election victor of the unified opposition titled: [Is it possible that the ECJ will annul the decrees of prima facie constitutional use of the Orban government in Hungary?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/75286/is-it-possible-that-the-ecj-will-annul-the-decrees-of-prima-facie-constitutional/76365#76365).

---

**Is there any case law by the European Court of Human Rights in a matter where a High Contracting Party was found to have deprived its people of their right to free elections? If so, what cases are they?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this has come before the Court.

Some prominent examples are -

1. [Mathieu-Mohin and Clerfayt v Belgium (1987)](https://www.eods.eu/elex/uploads/files/57cd780a57125-Mathieu-Mohin%20and%20Clerfayt%20v.%20Belgium.pdf), the first time Article 3 was before the European Court of Human Rights, on the complex Belgian system of balancing French-speaking and Dutch-speaking electoral institutions
2. Matthews v United Kingdom (1999), on whether people in Gibraltar should be able to vote in elections to the European Parliament
3. [Hirst v United Kingdom (No 2) (2005)](http://www.bailii.org/eu/cases/ECHR/2005/681.html), on whether the UK could have a blanket ban on voting applicable to all prisoners
4. [Riza and others v Bulgaria (2015)](https://hudoc.echr.coe.int/eng#%7B%22itemid%22:%5B%22001-158149%22%5D%7D), on selective interference with the electoral count

In all but the first of these, the Court found a violation of Article 3 of the Protocol. At other times, it has given deference to a State's particular processes, or ruled that a complaint was inadmissible because it did not pertain to the covered type of election.

You may be interested to read the Court's [guide](https://www.echr.coe.int/Documents/Guide_Art_3_Protocol_1_ENG.pdf) to its case-law on the topic (a 34-page PDF) which includes many more citations, and an explanation of the legal reasoning involved.

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site, amazing post!